# How to delete directory when some files in open mode using c#

Tags: c#

I have to delete root directory but some files open then it gives error "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

So, how to delete the directory when some files in open mode (I know using for each loop single file delete when it's open mode but I have to delete directory without for each loop.)

Comment: copy the file somewhere else  and then delete the directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting files in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504647/deleting-files-in-use)

Comment: @styx and in which way does this help to delete the used files? It's still not possible ;)

Comment: @HemangAghera you can close it and then re-open it. Think that you have a PDF open and you want to delete it's directory, you cant do it, its come from Windows itself

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Don't close this question. because it's a totally different question.

Comment: @styx I have to delete text file temporary generated by myself.

Comment: And why is this different? You want to delete opened files in the end.

Comment: because I have many files and every file check and I have also mentioned without for each loop how to delete the directory not file?

Comment: Have you ever had a look at the other SO question? For this problem it simply does not matter if you want to delete a directory with an opened file or the openend file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution whenever some files have been open and do delete directory then it's deleted but it gives throw an only error.So, Please use try catch block and ignore the error.

```
        try
        {
            Directory.Delete("path", true);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("Path");
        }
```

Comment: This is essentially a no-op, if it contains an open file: The direcotry will not be recreated, but the old one still exists

Comment: you can create more than one directory in inner directory. After the end of the directory and outer directory put your files and write down this code it's working. I have done in my code.

Comment: ... as long as there is no open file in it, which was the OQ

Answer (score 2):

You can't (at least not without closing those files).

The problem doesn't lie with your C# program, but with a severe limitation of the Windows kernel: It simply can't delete open (or locked) files (and thus not the directory, as it is now not empty).

You have two options:

- Use a mechanism such as unlocker to forcibly close the files, then delete them
- Have the application that opened the files close them, then delete

**EDIT**

Since you commented to add the information that the file is opened by your own application, things get easier:

- Close the file inside your application
- Run garbage collection to make sure your file handle is invalidated
- Deletion should now work